# Closed form solution of the normal density of a superfluid for the Bogoliubov spectrum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, integration, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

I've been trying to solve the following definite integral
$$
\int_0^\infty dx\, x^4\, \frac{e^{\sqrt{x^4+2 x^2}/Tp}}{\left(e^{\sqrt{x^4+2 x^2}/Tp}-1\right)^2}\, ,\quad Tp = \frac{T}{Un}
$$
This is the density of the normal part of a superfluid. However, so far I could not find any solution. I'd prefer an exact one but a good approximation would be also nice. (I do have the results for the limiting cases where one sets $\sqrt{x^4+2 x^2}\approx \sqrt{2}x$ and the case $\sqrt{x^4+2 x^2}\approx x^2 + 1$, so I am interested in the exact result or at least an approximation which is higher order than the limiting cases.)

(@Alex Trounev :) This is a follow up question of [Closed form solution to normal fluid density integral in the two fluid model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/575721/closed-form-solution-to-normal-fluid-density-integral-in-the-two-fluid-model))

Comment: Shouldn't $dx$ be as last term in integral expression ?

Comment: @Agnius Vasiliauskas I think people write it both ways. I like to write it close to the integral sign because it highlights that it is a symbol associated with the operation.

Comment: Maybe, but technically $$\int dx = \int 1 dx = x$$, so mathematically having $dx$ in front of expression means that you don't have what to integrate.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas I’ve seen the differential immediately after the integral innumerable times in books and papers.

Comment: @G.Smith Can be. But it doesn't mean that it is a good practice as I've explained in previous comment 

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas We’ll have to have a difference of opinion then.

Answer (score 1):

Since the integral depends only one parameter $Tp$, a good approach is to evaluate it numerically, since all you need is the dependence on this parameter. One could also try to evaluate analytically limiting cases: $Tp \ll 1$ and $Tp \gg 1$.

It is possible that by a clever substitution this integral can be reduced to one of the integrals in Gradshtein&Ryzhik, but there is a high chance that the solution is given in terms of special functions, which is often not better than just looking at the limiting cases. There is a fine difference between an *exact result* and a result that one can understand/interpret.

**Update**
I suggest using substitution $$y = \sqrt{x^4+2x^2}/(Tp) \Leftrightarrow x^2 = \sqrt{1+y^2(Tp)^2}-1$$, which reduces the integral to
$$\int_0^{+\infty}dx x^4 \frac{e^{\sqrt{x^4+2x^2}/Tp}}{(e^{\sqrt{x^4+2x^2}/Tp}-1)^2} =
\frac{(Tp)^2}{2}\int_0^{+\infty}dy \frac{y(\sqrt{1+y^2(Tp)^2}-1)^3}{\sqrt{1+y^2(Tp)^2}}\frac{e^y}{(e^y-1)^2}
$$
One can now obtain the required limiting cases by expanding $\sqrt{1+y^2(Tp)^2}$ in powers of $(Tp)^2$ (for small $Tp$) and by expanding $Tp\sqrt{\frac{1}{(Tp)^2}+y^2}$ in powers of $1/(Tp)^2$ (for $Tp \gg 1$). It is also easier to see whether the integral is reducible to any of those is the integral tables.

Comment: I agree that the result still might look awful, but I have a couple other integrals of the same type and I am hoping that their product/division is then simplified. (I think the two limiting cases, you suggested are essentially the ones mentioned in my question, i.e., $\sqrt{2}x$ for $Tp\ll 1$ and $x^2+1$ for $Tp\gg 1$.)

Comment: I am not sure that you deal correctly with the limiting cases: you are not taking limits, just expanding the square root for small $x$, which is incorrect, since the integral extends to infinity.
If $Tp \ll 1$, the exponent is very big, you neglect $1$ in the denominator and it becomes and integral that is probably reduced to a Gamma function. For $Tp>>1$ the exponent is small, so you can extend the exponent and again get a rather simple integral.

Comment: @mr.curious I added more details to my answer.

Comment: very helpful answer! Thanks :)

Comment: Just to be sure: This how I understand your point. Set $Tp^2\equiv u$ and then expand around $u=0$ for $Tp\ll 1$ and accordingly around $u=\infty$ for $Tp\gg 1$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You could expand in $Tp$, but since it is always squared, expanding in $(Tp)^2$ will save time.